# Vertical align navigation link text

Tags: html, css, navigation

My aim is to have the text links to be central inline with the search text, however i want the border around each of the links to stay how they are. basically how to i centre the text without moving the border.

I have tried adding this to the links .home .reviews .store .contact, however this just moves the border. 
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:20px;

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">

<nav class="navbar">
                <div class="navbarcontainer">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="reviews"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        <li class="store"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* NAVIGATION */


li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left; 
    border:1px black solid;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    height:60px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Cnb.jpg

Thankyou for any help

Comment: you need padding on `li > a`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work ;/

Comment: It could be easier if you can show us some code. So then we’ll know the context where the solution lies. But something like [that](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBOPLV).

Comment: You just need to add this to your css : li a {
 padding:20px 0px;
 display:block;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **line-height** property on links to vertically center:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Or, you can also use **vertical-align: middle**, but keep in mind that this approach is not fully compatible with all browsers (IE8+).

```
li {
    display:table;
    float:left; 
    border:1px black solid;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    height:60px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

a {
    padding: 19px 12px;
    display: block;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JozOgM)

Comment: For vertically center things, is always better using positioning instead of paddings.

Comment: Not totally sure about the always part. Whatever works. I try to always make the active click area as big as possible. In this case the whole borederd area.

Comment: Then, you can use padding combined with vertical align. Keep in mind that if you use padding for vertical centering, then you cannot apply another different padding to your components unless you create a new parent container. Moreover, if you suddenly change the menu height, you'll have to change the paddings of child elements.

Comment: My thinking behind that is I try to avoid writing heights into my css because of flexibility. But I’ll totally see your point. And in some way agree to it. It depends on the coder and context I guess.